# Qt binary file upload

Tags: qt

I'm using Zendesk API to upload files.  I can upload the files without a problem, but when I upload a binary file like a word document and download it after I get this error:

[image]

But if I click "OK" and select "Yes" on the next dialog, the word document opens properly:

[image]

If I upload a regular text file and then download it.  It opens without any problems.

This is the snippet of code I use to post my binary files.  I've tried following the RFC 1867 to see if I'm doing it right. Any thoughts or ideas?

```
QString boundNumber = QString::number(qrand(), 10);
QString bound = QString("---------------------------" + boundNumber);


QByteArray data(QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toLatin1());
data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"action\"\r\n\r\n");

data.append("\r\n");
data.append(QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toLatin1());
data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"");
data.append(finfo.fileName());
data.append("\"\r\n");
data.append("Content-Type:  application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"); //data type

fileUpload.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
data.append(fileUpload.readAll());
data.append("\r\n");
data.append("--" + bound + "--\r\n");  //closing boundary according to rfc 1867
data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"desc\"\r\n\r\n";
data += "file upload\r\n";
data += "\r\n";

data.append(QString(bound + "--\r\n").toLatin1());

fileUpload.close();
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/binary");
request.setRawHeader(QString("Content-Length").toLatin1(), QString::number(data.length()).toLatin1());
```

**Update**

I modified it so that its all returned as QByteArray by using toLatin1():

```
QByteArray data(QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toLatin1());
data.append(QString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"action\"\r\n\r\n").toLatin1());

data.append(QString("\r\n").toLatin1());
data.append(QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toLatin1());
data.append(QString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"").toLatin1());
data.append(finfo.fileName().toLatin1());
data.append(QString("\"\r\n").toLatin1());
data.append(QString("Content-Type:  application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").toLatin1()); //data type

fileUpload.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
data.append(fileUpload.readAll());
data.append(QString("\r\n").toLatin1());
data.append(QString("--" + bound + "--\r\n").toLatin1());  //closing boundary according to rfc 1867
data.append(QString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"desc\"\r\n\r\n").toLatin1());
data.append(QString("file upload\r\n").toLatin1());
data.append(QString("\r\n").toLatin1());


data.append(QString(bound + "--\r\n").toLatin1());
```

But still the same error for binary files

Comment: For such queries use `QHttpMultiPart` class.

Comment: Compare the downloaded file with the original file and check if you see the pattern how it breaks. Also I wouldn't use QString("...").toLatin1(), but just QByteArray("..."). Shouldn't matter much for the headers though.